# Why isn't INDF passing on its assigned value to FSR

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip, mplab

I am attempting to learn about how indirect addressing works. From the datasheet for the PIC16F877A, it states "Addressing this location uses contents of FSR to address data memory (not a physical register)" when referring to INDF. So I tried a super basic example:

```
movlw   D'26' 
movwf   FSR 
movf    INDF, W
```

Yet, when I debug, the value getting passed into FSR is 26 as expected but the value from INDF getting passed into W is 0 instead of 26. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

`INDF` reads the address supplied by `FSR`. So your code reads the `RCREG` register at address `0x1A` (D'26'):

```
movlw   D'26' 
movwf   FSR 
movf    INDF, W   ;read the value in the physical address D'26'
```

You had to select the bank you want to read from with the `RP0` and `RP1` bits, have a look into the datasheet it depends on the controller.